# How to store value in a table which represents MaxValue as infinite in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I have to model a table with multiple levels containing min and max values.

- Each level contains minimum and maximum values.
- The last level does not have any maximum value.

I would like to design my table with all the entries present(Default table) and the Level 5 MaxLevel left unfilled,

My table should look like below,

```
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+
| Id | Name    | MinLevel  | MaxLevel  | 
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Level 1 |         0 |  2        |
|  2 | Level 2 |         3 |  5        |
|  3 | Level 3 |         6 |  8        |
|  4 | Level 4 |         9 | 11        |
|  5 | Level 5 |  above 12 |           |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+
```

How to create a table like above in MySQL?

Comment: It's not really logical to have a "missing" value when that field is marked as `NOT NULL`.

Comment: However, if that field is a string (should probably not be one but `minLevel` is anyway) then you could just put an empty string to get that result

Comment: if all fields MUST be not null, the only option is setting the maxLevel to the max value allowed for that field without knowing precision/scale we can't figure out what that value would be.  Put anotherway, your requirements conflict you can't have: "Each level contains minimum and maximum values.
The last level does not have any maximum value."  Requirement 2 conflicts with the first.  maxLevel must allow Nulls and a trigger can ensure all but level 5 have a maxLevel > minLevel; and the maxlevel for level 5 is Null.

Comment: I would like to set that MaxLevel as infinite in the table